# React | Update part of object and set state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to update part of an object in React and set the state. I have got it working but it seems like I'm going about it the completely wrong way.

I have an object in the state which is set when the component mounts. I have a checkbox which uses an objects selected property. Essentially on the click of this checkbox I want to set the state and toggle the property. Which I am doing by `post.selected = !post.selected`.

The difficulty comes when I want to update the state to reflect this change, I am going through the whole of the original object, looking for the post. Updating the post and then updating the state. Is this really how it has to be done? Or can I directly update this value itself and target this within the set state function?

```
onItemClick(post, is_active = true) {
    const posts = this.state.posts;
    let postType = is_active ? 'active' : 'not-active';

    const parentCategory = posts.find(statePosts => {
       return posts[postType].id === post.id;
    });

    const foundPost = parentCategory[postType].find(selectedPost => selectedPost.id === post.id);
    foundPost.selected = !foundPost.selected;

    this.setState({posts: posts});
}
```

It just seems a bit long winded to do it like that when all I want to do is update that one object in the state.

Getting the posts:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
    this.setState({posts: props.posts});
}
```

Posts loop:

```
{
posts.active.map((post) => {
    return (
        <View key={post.id}>
            <CheckBox
                checkBoxColor={"green"}
                checkedCheckBoxColor={"blue"}
                onClick={() => {
                    this.onItemClick(post)
                }}
                isChecked={post.selected}
                rightText={post.description} />
        </View>
    )
})
```

}

Comment: Could you post more code? Like the place where you call onItemClick, and your constructor?

Comment: I have updated the question to have more code

Comment: I am not using a constructor @iagowp

Answer (score 1):

Store your post such that id is the key and post is the object.  Then while updating do something like posts.active= {...posts.active,...post};

Answer (score 0):

Use spread operator with new post object to update posts object.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you please elaborate more?